# Are user names in TFS checkins immutable

Tags: tfs

In TFS 2010 the user name captured as part of a checkin is the "user login" from Active Directory. My company uses a format of x12345 for user logins.

The organisation has recently started recycling logins so for example x54321 2 years ago could have been John Doe, today John has left the company and the number reallocated to Jane Smith. This means that the TFS 2010 history will show that code was checked in by x54321 however the individual represented by that number will have changed. This is of course a problem as it compromises our ability to audit our code and understand who made certain changes.

My understanding is that TFS 2012 uses the Active Directory "Display Name" for the user. 
Is this immutable? I.e. in the scenario above will code checked 2 years ago for login x54321 show as "John Doe" in the TFS history and code checked in today by x54321 show as "Jane Smith" or will the history be altered to show that "Jane Smith" made the older checkin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A TFS 2012 Project collection associates items to Active Directory SIDs, so if the AD user is deleted then another user is created with the same username they will not be considered the same person.  However I am unsure what will be displayed in history as TFS can not look up the user.

The TFS 2012 Warehouse appears to keep the domain, sid, friendly name, domain login and email.  And has a dimension for changeset, which I don't believe stores the exact changes made but would let you lookup the users name if needed.

Although it's not relevant, i'd love to know why your it depart reuses logins, while tfs 2012 may not be an issue I'm sure there's lots of others that will be.

Comment: I don't know the exact reason but I suspect that there is some software somewhere that cannot accept a user id longer than 5 digits.

Comment: Something that might be usefull to this awnser is to add is that when the reverse happens (a person leaves the company, returns and gets a different number) the old user can be replaced by the new user using the command: " /change /fromdomain:Contoso1 /todomain:ContosoPrime /account:hholt /toaccount:jpeoples"

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you are wondering if you update the Display Names in AD if those will be reflected in TFS checkins that happened 2 years ago.  In TFS 2010 and newer, the answer is yes, those names will get updated for old TFS checkins.  TFS has an identity sync process that runs periodically so once you make the changes in AD you will need to wait for the sync to happen before the changes are reflected.

On tfspreview.com and with TFS 2012, users have the ability to set custom display names directly in TFS so AD can be completely by-passed.

Comment: Not quite, the AD account will be deleted, then a new account created but with the same user login. In 2010 the history displays the user login so even though it's a different AD account it looks like the same user.